# Org-Mode: How to create an "org mode markup" keybinding?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I know I can use `*bold*`, `/italic/`, `_underline_`, `=verbatim=`, `~code~`, and `+strike-through+` to [apply markup to text](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html) in `org-mode`. But how do I create key bindings for applying these changes to a region of text? For example, if I want to make some text bold, is there an easier way than

1. navigating to the front of the text
2. prefixing it with a `*`
3. navigating to the end of the text
4. appending a `*`?

I can't seem to find any command that "bolds" a stretch of text, such as `org-make-region-bold`. Is there such a command?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Mark you region
2. Click `C-c C-x C-f *` for **bold**, `C-c C-x C-f /` for *italic* etc.

> `org-emphasize` is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `org.el`.
>
> ```
> (org-emphasize &optional CHAR)
> ```
>
> Insert or change an emphasis, i.e. a font like bold or italic.
> If there is an active region, change that region to a new emphasis.
> If there is no region, just insert the marker characters and position
> the cursor between them.
> CHAR should be the marker character.  If it is a space, it means to
> remove the emphasis of the selected region.
> If CHAR is not given (for example in an interactive call) it will be
> prompted for.

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of [`electric-pair-mode`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun%2Felectric-pair-mode.html)<sup>1</sup> to facilitate insertion of mark-up characters in `org-mode`. Add the following code to your init-file:

```el
(electric-pair-mode 1)

(defvar org-electric-pairs '((?\* . ?\*) (?/ . ?/) (?= . ?=)
                             (?\_ . ?\_) (?~ . ?~) (?+ . ?+)) "Electric pairs for org-mode.")

(defun org-add-electric-pairs ()
  (setq-local electric-pair-pairs (append electric-pair-pairs org-electric-pairs))
  (setq-local electric-pair-text-pairs electric-pair-pairs))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-add-electric-pairs)
```

With this in place, all you need to do to wrap a region with mark-up characters is press the corresponding character (`*`, `/`, `=`, `_`, `~`, or `+`) once.

As an additional benefit, Emacs will automatically insert matching pairs of mark-up characters at point if there is no region. For example, pressing <kbd>*</kbd> will insert `**` and leave point between the two chars so you can continue typing without having to move point.

---

<sup>1</sup> This mode is built-in; there's no need to install any third-party packages to use it.

Comment: Thank you!  

Honestly, this is the cleanest and most straightforward answer. The sweet surprise is that `electric-pair-mode` also applies the pair to a selected region. I always though that electric pairs were for inserting pairs-only.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `*` and `/` are commonly used in typical Org mode documents e.g. `*` begins a header. Similarly if you're typing a slash in longform text e.g. there is an extra slash you need to delete every time.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`wrap-region`](https://github.com/rejeep/wrap-region.el) package (also available on Melpa) to wrap a region with any character of your choice. This of course can be configured per major mode.

```el
(require 'wrap-region)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'wrap-region-mode)

(wrap-region-add-wrapper "=" "=" nil 'org-mode) ; select region, hit = then region -> =region= in org-mode
(wrap-region-add-wrapper "*" "*" nil 'org-mode) ; select region, hit * then region -> *region* in org-mode
(wrap-region-add-wrapper "/" "/" nil 'org-mode) ; select region, hit / then region -> /region/ in org-mode
(wrap-region-add-wrapper "_" "_" nil 'org-mode) ; select region, hit _ then region -> _region_ in org-mode
(wrap-region-add-wrapper "+" "+" nil 'org-mode) ; select region, hit + then region -> +region+ in org-mode
```

The [`expand-region`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) package complements this package very well (also available in Melpa).

#### Usage

- You select the word or phrase using the key binding you chose for `er/expand-region`.
- Hit `*` to emphasize that region as bold (in `org-mode`).

Answer (score 0):

Users of Evil can employ [the evil-surround minor mode](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-surround) to deal with various kinds of markup. You can either add markup to visual selection with `S` (by default) or to text objects in normal mode with `ys`.

You can also change or delete some markers. But, [to change or delete markers that aren't known to evil-surround by default, you'll need to add them to Evil as text objects](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-surround/issues/141).